# robots.txt disallow /variable_dir_name/directory

Tags: directory, robots.txt, noindex

I need to disallow /variable_dir_name/directory via robots.txt

I use:

Disallow: */directory
Noindex: */directory

is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following *should* work in your robots.txt:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /*/directory
```

Further reading from Google: [Block or remove pages using a robots.txt file](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there was the opportunity of GoogleBot that allowed to use these in the Robots.txt:

- Noindex
- Nofollow
- Crawl-delay

But seen on the [GoogleBlog-News](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/07/a-note-on-unsupported-rules-in-robotstxt.html) they will no longer support those (0,001% used) commands anymore from September 2019 on. So you should only use meta tags anymore for these on your page to be safe for the future.

What you really should do, is the following:

- Disallow via robots.txt and
- Noindex already indexed documents via Google Search Console